How can a parent frame "interrupt" the `window.prompt` of a `Origin-Agent-Cluster`-isolated child frame?
(Please put aside the utility/inadvisability of window.prompt usage - that's not what this question is about. I'm using this case to debug a broader issue of frame-frame interference.)

I'm investigating how the window.prompt of a child frame (that is performance-isolated with Origin-Agent-Cluster:?1) is being "interrupted" (i.e. abruptly closed without user interaction) by some unknown code in a parent (or perhaps sibling) frame.
Origin-Agent-Cluster isolation is relevant here because it prevents synchronous code in the child and parent from blocking one another.
Things I know:

A frame can interrupt another Origin-Agent-Cluster-isolated frame's prompt/alert/etc. by calling prompt/alert/etc. itself (regardless of parent/child relationship). The other frame's prompt closes, and the new one appears in its place.
A parent frame can interrupt a Origin-Agent-Cluster-isolated child frame's prompt/alert/etc. by navigating (i.e. window.location.reload(), window.location.href=...)
window.focus() does not interrupt another frame's prompt/alert/etc.
Whatever is causing this is also able to disrupt/cancel an "Are you sure you want to leave?" confirm prompt (set via onbeforeunload). This is pretty surprising to me, since it suggests that a site could kind of make itself kind of "unexitable".

This applies to Chrome Linux, Version 123.0.6312.105, at least. I'm not sure about other browsers. Unfortunately I'm not able to consistently reproduce instances of the "interruption" since I think the root cause is third-party ad code that is running in the parent frame, and it has only happened a few times in the last month (though frequency does seem to be increasing a bit lately).
I know that parent navigation and parent/sibling frame calls to prompt/alert/etc. are not the cause. The interruption happens without navigation or other prompts/alerts/popups/etc appearing. It just closes the iframe's prompt, and that's it.
An ideal answer to this question would simply give a list of tested/viable ways in which a parent or sibling frame could "interrupt" a frame's prompt/alert/etc. - without causing a navigation or another prompt/popup/etc. to appear. There could be many causes, so the more possibilities listed, the better.
I suspect there could be behavioral differences between browsers on this issue, so answers that are only tested in Chrome are okay.
Addendum:

Originally this question had a big mistake: I was mixing up Origin-Agent-Cluster performance isolation with cross-origin isolation (COEP/CORP headers).

Per @Kaiido's comment RE browser extensions potentially being a cause: It's possible, but unlikely I think. I've only got DarkReader installed, and it was on the "off" state last time this happened. I've also received many user reports about problems that I'm quite sure are caused by this issue, including on Android Chrome. It tends to happen when the advert frame is loading/refreshing. Another effect (alongside the prompt closing effect) is that focus is stolen from any focussed textarea (which initially led me to believe this whole issue was caused by window.focus() in another frame). That said, I can't know for sure that this is the same issue, but I can confirm that the prompt-closing effect tends to happen for me when the advert frame is loading/refreshing. I'm quite sure it's the same underlying problem, but I don't have a lot of data to go by.



First, you'd need to detect that a prompt/alert/etc is occurring  - I take it you solved that part already since you now want to deal with a known state

@JaromandaX that's probably something running periodically. If it was based on an event the prompt would certainly not show at all.

You're sure it's not something related to a browser extension?

@Kaiido - I can't tell if you missed my point or not

@JaromandaX I'm not sure either. I assume you meant the frame has access to some kind of event for when that prompt would be displayed, right? Then my point is that if that was the case, they would react sooner than needed to show the dialog. Here OP said they do see the popover and that it gets shut down later. So the most probable situation is something like setInterval(() => closeDialog(), 3000), which would not require an event nor to know if the dialog is open.

Give the iframe a sandbox without allow-modals.

@HeikoTheißen The prompt in the cross-origin-isolated child is open. I want to know what could cause it to suddenly close without user interaction (not what could cause it to not open in the first place).

One possible method might be to create a separate child frame, and trigger an alert (or prompt/confirm/etc.) within it, but then immediately destroy that iframe from the parent. The alert should "cancel" the one in the original child frame, but then be itself destroyed via the destruction of its own frame.
That said, I don't think that's what is happening with my issue, because I don't see any other prompts appear even momentarily. The prompt in the cross-origin-isolated child frame seems to just "gracefully disappear" (without any user interaction).

If you see this happening on your machine, can't you debug it then? By breaking into the outer frame's code and executing it step by step? Or even installing Chromium as debug build and debugging source level (figure out what function is responsible for closing a dialog, then set a breakpoint and look at the stack for hints what could have triggered it)?

It's not something I can reproduce at will, unfortunately. It only happens a couple of times a week at most (that I notice), and there's no forewarning, and no way to diagnose what happened after-the-fact, as far as I can see. RE: "Or even installing Chromium as debug build and debugging source level" I'd like to try to avoid digging down into Chromium code if I can :') But yes, certainly an option if it comes to it.

Here's my best attempt so far:
The main frame loads an iframe and produces an alert. After one second, the iframe communicates next ad to the main frame and "asynchronously" (after 0 seconds) produces its own alert. This closes the alert of the main frame.
The main frame receives the next ad communication and navigates the iframe. This closes the alert of the iframe.
Since the iframe's alert is produced and immediately closed again, you don't notice it. The overall effect is just that the main frame's alert is closed.
main_frame.html
<body onload="alert('alert')">
  <iframe id="a" src="http://other.domain/iframe.html"></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  onmessage = function() {
    a.src = "about:blank";
  };
  </script>
</body>

iframe.html
<body onload="setTimeout(function() {
  parent.postMessage('next ad','*');
  setTimeout(() => alert(''));
}, 1000)">
</body>

This is rather similar to the author's own solution and I can imagine that ad frames work in such a way.

Apologies!! I realised from your earlier comment on the question about not being able to reproduce the first dot point in my question (your comment about that is no longer there for some reason) that I made a big mistake: I was mixing up Origin-Agent-Cluster performance isolation with cross-origin isolation (COEP/CORP headers).

That said, the question is about a prompt/alert that is initially open in the child, which can be plainly seen (i.e. not momentarily), and then it suddenly disappears due to something the parent does, but without the parent needing to trigger navigations or itself open a prompt/alert. As I mentioned in the bounty notice: "so long as it doesn't navigate itself or the child frame in question" and my existing answer covers the "momentary parent prompt" case.
